# place cursor at end of text in memo field (.net app)

Tags: .net

is there a way when a page opens, to place the cursor at the end of a large memo field so users can automatically start entering text at the end of the field, rather than have them scroll down first?

thanks

DD

Comment: You really ought to work on your terminology. Not a single term is familiar to me. Do you mean TextBox and Caret? Is this web or winforms? What language?

Comment: c#, textbox displaying a sql ntext field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go it
tbPositionCursor.Select(tbPositionCursor.Text.Length, 0);